# Как добавить код состояния http к ответу в flask_restful

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

С некоторых пор пишу API на flask_restful, как в ответе указать код состояния http?

Советы и комментарии к коду приветствуются

```
from flask import jsonify, request
from flask_restful import Resource
from dbase import profiles


class Profile(Resource):
    """Операции с профилем"""
    def get(self):
        """Получить сведения о своем профиле"""
        json_data = request.get_json(force=True)
        profile_token = json_data['profile_token']
        profile = profiles.get_full_profile(profile_token=profile_token)
        if profile:
            # Операция прошла успешно
            return jsonify({'result': True, 'profile': profile}) # здесь нужен код 200
        else:
            # Не верный токен, пользователь не найден
            return jsonify({'result': False, 'error': 'User not exists'}) # здесь нужен код 404
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно удалить jsonify() и через запятую указать желаемый код. С jsonify() так не работает, почему не знаю

```
from flask import jsonify, request
from flask_restful import Resource
from dbase import profiles


class Profile(Resource):
    """Операции с профилем"""
    def get(self):
        """Получить сведения о своем профиле"""
        json_data = request.get_json(force=True)
        profile_token = json_data['profile_token']
        profile = profiles.get_full_profile(profile_token=profile_token)
        if profile:
            # Операция прошла успешно
            return { 'result': True, 'profile': profile }, 200
        else:
            # Не верный токен, пользователь не найден
            return { 'result': False, 'error': 'User not exists' }, 404
```

Comment: в `jsonify` просто нет такой возможности https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/src/flask/json/__init__.py#L271